# Why is this PHP switch statement skipping over "Sunday"?

Tags: php, datetime, switch-statement

As Saturday night at midnight passes, for some reason it skips over Sunday! Every other day displays just fine. Why does it skip over Sunday?

What's the best way to set up this switch statement to iterate through the days and display some content?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');

$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date("w"));

function areWeOpen($day)
{
    $day = (int)$day;
    $timenow = date('g:i a');

    switch ($day) {
        case ($day == 0):
            echo "<h1>I cherish your love at <span       class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span> this Sunday0!</h1>
                <br>
                <img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I  Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;

        case ($day == 1):
            echo " <h1>It's definately <span  class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span> Monday1 and I love you even today! :)</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;

        case ($day == 2):
            echo "<h1>It's <span class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span> Tuesday2!! I love you..... :)<br>Scan or click this to hear love message</h1>
                <a href=\"http://boxoflove.us/audio/honeyloveyou.mp3\"  target=\"_blank\">
                <img class=\"loveaudio\" alt=\"Who I Am\"  src=\"http://boxoflove.us/lovetime/images/qr/honeyloveyouqr.png\" title=\"Who I  Am\" /></a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <iframe width=\"320\" height=\"280\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/exgHwy-Q5ik?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <br>
                <br>
                <audio id=\"audio1\" src=\"audio/siren.mp3\" controls></audio>
                <br><img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;

        case ($day == 3):
            echo "<h1>It's <span class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span> Wednesday3 and the love I have for you seems to be increasing!</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img src=\"http://mobilesavior.com/images/mobilesaviorhomeqr200.jpg\" alt=\"Home QR\"><br><img class=\"boximg\" src=\"images/boxoflove5.jpg\" alt\"Box of love\"     />
                <br>
                <audio id=\"audio1\" src=\"siren.mp3\" controls></audio>
                <br><img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;

        case ($day == 4):
            echo "<h1>It's <span class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span> Thursday4, and I love you!</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;

        case ($day == 5):
            echo "<h1>Hello! It's <span class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span> Friday5! I am definately in love with you, but I am also your friend.</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;

        case ($day == 6):
            echo "<h1>It's <span class=\"timeColor\">$timenow</span>        Saturday6, hooray!! I love you! Hooray!! ;)</h1>
                <br>
                <img class=\"heart2\" src=\"/images/redheart300s.png\" alt=\"I  Beat For You!\" title=\"I Beat For You!\">";
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think it should be `case n:` instead of `case ($day == n):`.

Comment: Thanks! It now displays "Sunday's" content but gives this error:           Notice: Use of undefined constant n - assumed 'n' in /home/bigfootbud/public_html/boxoflove.us/lovetime/index.php on line 25  Live here http://boxoflove.us/lovetime/index.php

Comment: Don't use `case n:`, you should use `case 0:`, `case 1:`, .... , `case 6:`

Comment: Thanks! No error! :) Just so I get this right.... the numbers after "case" represent the day of the week because of the "w" in ----> areWeOpen(date("w")); function????

Comment: Yes, and the counting starts at `0`.

Comment: Not sure if you saw this? but why did all the other days work fine before?

Comment: In that case, your switch statement was comparing `boolean` values instead of numerical values, `0` is actually `false` as a `boolean` that is why only this day wasn't working.